# separating threads but still keeping a common variable in java

Tags: java, multithreading, updates

My project group is creating a traffic simulation and we are not sure how to split threads properly. We have the update method below that has 1 variable delta. Now we want to split both for loops (updating vehicles in the first and the second updates all intersections etc). How does one split these into 2 threads yet still being able to give them the same value for delta? Is this even possible? We can only get it to work putting the entire method into 1 thread, but then we can not split them.

EDIT: the delta is a constantly changing variable (time passed) this is the reason it's hard to get both to use the same delta.

```
public void update(double delta){

    for (int i = 0; i < this.vehicles.size(); i++) {
        this.vehicles.get(i).update(delta);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.updateables.size(); i++) {
        this.updateables.get(i).update(delta);
    }
    this.simulationTime += delta;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to run in parallel? Do you want to update the cars and then after they're finished update the tables?

Comment: Are you saying the delta will change during `vehicle.get(i).update(delta)`? Or do you want that task to complete with a single value of delta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this.vehicles` is a List, or something along those lines, create a parallel stream.

```
this.vehicles.stream().parallel().forEach(v->v.update(delta));
```

Then they should be run in parallel.

An alternative way, if you want more control over the process, use an executor service.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

Then submit each task.

```
List<Future<?>> futures = this.vehicles.map(
    v->service.submit(
        ()->v.update(delta)
    )
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then to make sure all of the tasks complete.

```
futures.forEach(future->{
    try{
        future.get();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //two types of exceptions they both should be handled appropriately.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, delta may vary.

You can create two seperate Threads, for example here the one for the vehicles:

```
public class VehiclesUpdater extends Thread {

    double delta;
    List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public VehiclesUpdater(double delta, List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
         this.delta = delta;
         this.vehicles = vehicles;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<vehicles.size();i++) {
            vehicles.get(i).update(delta);
        }
    }


}
```

Then, instead of calling the loop, just do as follows:

```
public void update(double delta) {

   Thread t = new VehiclesUpdater(delta, vehicles);
   t.start();


   //the same here for the Updateables
}
```

EDIT:
Because you are concerning time issues, you may try an Observer/Observable-approach.

Let your Vehicle-class and your Updateable-class extend the Observer class: [Observer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)

In the class which computes the delta-value(s), implement the Observable interface. If it changes, call the `setChanged()` method and after that the  `notifyObservers()` method and give delta or an Double-Wrapper as param to it:

```
Double wrapper = new Double(delta);
setChanged();
notifyObservers(wrapper);
```

In your vehicle-class, you have to override the `update-method` of Observer:

```
//
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    this.updateDelta((Double)arg);
}
```

I just called your original update-method updateDelta for clarification - it should be possible to use method-overloading here as long as your update-method will use another param (double) and has the same method-head with public void update(...).

Comment: In this case you give the update method a delta, but our delta constantly changes (it's the time passes that we use to calculate speed and distances etc.) So I do not feel like this solution would work?

Comment: But you did also in your post. your update-method has delta as param and then it is used on each vehicle and updateable.